# Yii2 : Active Record - joinWith is Optimized?

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Please let me start with the example below:

I have 3 tables:

```
users(id,name,family)
roles(id,user_id,chart_id,name,code)
chart(id,name)
```

Relations:

```
users-roles = 1-n
roles-users = 1-1
roles-chart = 1-1
```

Yii active record classes:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord {
    public function getRoles(){
        return $this->hasMany(Role::className(),['user_id' => 'id']);
    }
}

class Role extends ActiveRecord {
    public function getUser(){
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(),['id' => 'user_id']);
    }

    public function getChart(){
        return $this->hasOne(Chart::className(),['id' => 'chart_id']);
    }
}
```

So I want roles and use this code:

```
$roles = Role::find()
    ->select('roles.id,roles.user_id,roles.chart_id,roles.name,roles.code')
    ->joinWith([
        'user' => function($q){
            $q->select('id,name,family');
        },
        'chart' => function($q){
            $q->select('id,name');
        }
    ])
->all();
```

When run this code , Yii create three query;

First query:

```
SELECT 
    `roles`.`id`, `roles`.`user_id`,
    `roles`.`chart_id`, `roles`.`name`,
    `roles`.`code`
FROM `roles`
 LEFT JOIN `users` ON `roles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
 LEFT JOIN `chart` ON `roles`.`chart_id` = `chart`.`id`
```

Second query:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `family` FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (1, 3)
```

Third query:

```
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `chart` WHERE `id`=1
```

Is this optimized?

Why can I achieve the result in the **first query** !

Why Yii does not combine three queries ? Like the code below:

```
SELECT 
    `roles`.`id`, `roles`.`user_id`,
    `roles`.`chart_id`, `roles`.`name`,
    `roles`.`code`,
    `chart`.`id`,`users`.`id`,`users`.`name`,`users`.`family`
FROM `roles`
 LEFT JOIN `users` ON `roles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
 LEFT JOIN `chart` ON `roles`.`chart_id` = `chart`.`id`
```

Comment: In final sql, you have for instance three 'id' fields. How could Yii populate respective models (roles, chart and user) 'id' field ?

Comment: yii can use aliases for primary key such as `role.id yiipk1` or any rule can be used.